# Typescript function return type based on class property

Tags: typescript

I have the following class and function:

```
class Test {
  prop: string;
  otherProp: number;

  constructor() {
    const result = doSomething<Test>('prop');
  }
}

function doSomething<T>(propName: keyof T): ???? {
  // ,,,
}
```

There is a way with typescript that I can return from the function the same type as the property that the function gets. In the above example, the return type should be `string`. If I call it with `otherProp` the return type should be number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an extra type parameter to capture the actual type of the key passed in (lets call it `K`. You can then use `K` to index into `T` (ie use a type query)

```
class Test {
    prop: string;
    otherProp: number;

    constructor() {
        const result = doSomething(this, 'prop');
    }
}

function doSomething<T, K extends keyof T>(target: T, propName: keyof T): T[K] {
    return this[propName];
}
```

I modified the example above to pass in some parameter with the type `T` to infer both `K` and `T` from parameters. Typescript does not support partial type inference so we can't specify `T` and have `K` inferred. So if we don't have a parameter of type `T` we would need to write:

```
class Test {
    prop: string;
    otherProp: number;

    constructor() {
        const result = doSomething<Test, 'prop'>('prop');
    }
}

function doSomething<T, K extends keyof T>(propName: keyof T): T[K] {
    return this[propName];
}
```

A better version s to use a function taht returns a function, and have `T` fixed in the first call and `K` inferred in the second:

```
class Test {
    prop: string;
    otherProp: number;

    constructor() {
        const result = doSomething<Test>()('prop');
    }
}

function doSomething<T>() {
    return function <K extends keyof T>(propName: keyof T): T[K] {
        return this[propName];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I must pass two parameters? Can't it work like my example?

Comment: @undefined added versions without the extra parameter.

Comment: Thanks, helpful as always.