# How to properly TypeScript getter function so it narrows the return type to a interface property type?

Tags: typescript, types, type-narrowing

I want to properly type function which accepts the prop name and returns an object `{ value: <prop type> }`

```js
function getValueOfProp<
  O extends object,            // O is an object (interface)
  K extends keyof O = keyof O  // K is property key type
>(key: K): { value: O[K] }     // it returns { value: O[K] }
{
  // some implementation...
}
```

For instance when you do it lodash way:

```js
import { get } from 'lodash'
const obj = { prop1: 5, prop2: string }
const a = get(obj, 'prop1') // a resolved to a number type
const b = get(obj, 'prop2') // b resolved to a string type
```

It's easy to define such a function:

```js
function get<O extends Object, K extends keyof O>(obj: O, key: K): O[K] {
  return obj[key]
}
```

But when you want to be more generic and remove the object from the function interface, it becomes tricky:

```js
interface TMyInterface {
  prop1: number
}

function getValueOfProp<
  O extends TMyInterface = TMyInterface,
  K extends keyof O = keyof O // Defaulting to "keyof O" to avoid
                              // a need to pass this type every time
                              // (but it breaks proper typing)
>(key: K): { value: O[K] } {
  // some implementation...
}

interface TMyNewInterface extends TMyInterface {
  prop2: string
}

const a = getValueOfProp<TMyNewInterface>('prop2')
// a resolves to 
// {
//   value: number | string // <-- I want it to get narrowed to 'prop2' type (string)
// }
```

It works though if I pass the keyof type explicitly:

```js
const a = getValueOfProp<TMyNewInterface, 'prop2'>('prop2')
// a resolves to 
// {
//   value: string // <-- Exactly what I wanted but I don't like double typing 'prop2'
// }
```

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54365283/typescript-function-return-type-based-on-class-property), but it suggests using double func call like `getValueOfProp<TMyNewInterface>()('prop2')` which works fine but I don't like this double fn call `()('prop2')`

Does anyone know how to properly type `getValueOfProp` function so it resolves to the exact prop type of a given interface with no need to pass prop key as a type and avoiding double fn calls?

Comment: It does not makes sence as it does not depend on object type at all

Comment: So there can be only K type argumemt

Comment: TypeScript does not have partial type inference. So currying (as described in your question) is your only option.